Key error when calling function from another script. Fetching data from RCSB Database
I have the following piece of code, which is meant to fetch certain data from the RCSB database such as information regarding the resolution of a PDB structure, associated UniProt ID etc.
def fetch_pdb_data(*pdb_ids):
    url = "https://data.rcsb.org/graphql"
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    variables = {"entry_ids": list(pdb_ids)}
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json={"query": PDB_GRAPHQL_QUERY, "variables": variables})

    if response.status_code == 200:
        result = response.json()
        print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))  # Debugging output to print the response structure
        
        # Ensure the 'data' field is present and check the structure of entries
        if 'data' in result:
            for entry in result['data']['entries']:
                print(f"Entry: {entry}")  # Debugging: Print the full entry structure

            # Try constructing the final output while being more cautious with missing keys
            return {
                entry['rcsb_id']: {
                    "resolution": entry.get('rcsb_entry_info', {}).get('resolution_combined', [None])[0],
                    "entities": [get_entity_info(entity) for entity in entry.get('polymer_entities', [])]
                }
                for entry in result['data']['entries']
            }
        else:
            print(f"Error in data response: {result}")
            return {"error": result.get("errors", "Unknown error")}
    else:
        print(f"HTTP error {response.status_code}")
        return {"error": f"HTTP error {response.status_code}"}
    
def get_entity_info(entity):
    print(f"Entity: {entity}")  # Debugging: Print each entity to check its structure
    # Check if pdbx_description exists before trying to access it
    return {
        "molecule": entity.get('pdbx_description', "N/A"),  # Access pdbx_description directly
        "uniprot_ids": entity.get('rcsb_polymer_entity_container_identifiers', {}).get('uniprot_ids', [])
    }

The code takes the following graphql as an entry to be able to pull the desired information from the database:
PDB_GRAPHQL_QUERY = """
query structure ($entry_ids: [String!]!) {
    entries(entry_ids: $entry_ids) {
        rcsb_id
        rcsb_entry_info {
            resolution_combined
        }
        polymer_entities {
            pdbx_description
            rcsb_polymer_entity_container_identifiers {
                uniprot_ids
            }
        }
    }
}
"""

I have tried to ensure that the graphql contains the appropriate formatting. Before this, I got an
Error 2: File not found
even if the script and asscoaited files are in the same folder. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong at this point. The expected outcome here should be that a sister code should be able to use what I pasted above and create a .csv output containing: PDB Id, resolution and UniProt ID.

I do not see any query name structure on my Postman query list, one close query that matches your described query is  entries. can you elaborate more on this? also, it would be helpful if you add script file structure tree like script-1.py, script-2.py
